# problem in Load balance the data in multiple background service

Tags: database, algorithm, kubernetes, architecture

I have a database table which is called `Queue` that contains some data. I have multiple background services which are running in K8 environment. The job of background services is to pull the data from `Queue` table and process it.

**Problem Statement:**
In current scenario, data is not load balance among each service as one service will pull all the data when it runs and other services will remain idle or process very less data. How can I over come this situation so that data is distributed uniformly among the services?

Comment: Are you scaling up/down your kubernetes cluster based on the items in your Queue? Or are the number of PODs fairly static?

Comment: They are mostly static but in future we can change as well as per considering future load.

Comment: Then you can have a database job which runs periodically and assign each job to one of the workers (with a round robin algo for example). Like job1 - worker1, job2 - worker3, ... jobN - worker2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem I see with this approach is that the workers are running in kubernetes cluster and their pod names are dynamic as when we restart or redeploy the worker in k8 it's pod names get changed that's why we cannot assign job with worker name as you mentioned.

Comment: Well you can use environment variables and fieldRefs to assign ids to pods: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Comment: Thanks for this..will try this and let you know

Comment: Did it work for you?